# Apache, why I'm getting a redirect loop?

Tags: apache

I have apache 2.4 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "http://www.domain.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.domain.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

And I'm always getting a redirect loop from www.domain.com to www.domain.com. Tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.domain.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Nothing. Only works, when I leave `<VirtualHost *:443>...</VirtualHost>` alone. But then of course no http->https redirect, and no non-www to www.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the first clause to this: (the only thing I changed was redirect to https instead)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.domain.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nope, it's the same.

Comment: Make sure you don't have another redirect somewhere else. If you're using Wordpress, check your options, it might have unwanted redirects.